# Function doesn't work on page (WordPress)

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I have made a page in Wordpress with a form like this:

```
<form id="contact" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
    <h3>Beschikbaarheid</h3>
    <h4>Geef uw beschikbare werktijden door.</h4>
    <fieldset>
      <input placeholder="Uw naam" type="text" name="name" value="<?= $name ?>" tabindex="1">
      <span class="error"><?= $name_error ?></span>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <input placeholder="Uw Emailadres" type="text" name="email" value="<?= $email ?>" tabindex="2">
      <span class="error"><?= $email_error ?></span>
    </fieldset>
```

I have put the functions for this form in functions.php but it doesn;t work. What is the proper way to make a functioning form?

Comment: Share your functions that you put in `functions.php` and I'm not sure why aren't you escaping any data?

Comment: if (empty($_POST["select-5"])) {
    $tijd_error = "Kies een tijd!";
  } else {
    $tijd_vrijdag = $_POST["select-5"];
  } This is one of the functions I have made for the form

Answer (score 1):

Best way for handlig forms - use `admin-post.php` and don`t forget valid and escaping data.
Good tutorial [here](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/handling-form-submissions/)

Change your form action to `<?php echo admin_url('admin-post.php'); ?>`. Create field with name action:

```
<input name="action" value="my_action">
```

Create hooks in your functions.php file.

```
add_action('admin_post_my_action', 'form_handler');
add_action('admin_post_nopriv_my_action', 'form_handler');
function form_handler(){
    // handle your form. Use $_POST here
}
```

And do not forget use `nonce`.

Answer (score 0):

[Updated]

Set your form action as below, so that it submits the data to this page and doesn't redirect to another page. And you have to change the input field `name` attribute. Not sure why `name` as the value of `name` attribute isn't working, otherwise everything works fine. I've tested on my local dev environment.

```
<form id="contact" method="post" action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
```

Sorry, I didn't know that there is a request handler. Here are the details https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_post_(action) and here is the modified tag

```
<form id="contact" method="post" action="<?php echo esc_url( admin_url( 'admin-post.php' ) ); ?>">
```

Comment: Need use admin-post.php as action. See official documentation.